# Not showing bootmenu

Tags: operating-systems

I had both Ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7 on my Hp desktop and it was working properly.Now the problem is when I tried to boot the system it is not going to the boot menu instead it continuously blinks Display status as " 640X .." and recommended settings as 13..X....(sorry i dont remember the exact values) and is not going to the boot menu. When i used Ubundu live boot CD to boot the system i am able to see the folders.Is this due to the problem with display settings? How will I correct this problem?.

monitor model is Hp v185e( i tried to change settings using menu button on the monitor but it is changing back to 640X.. ) (i also tried change the settings from BIOS but it changed the resolution to some 1024 X .. and is not working) \

I can go to command prompt using my Windows 7 CD. Can  i change the resolution
using regedit command?

Manju

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about trouble with booting into a personal OS installation, not any specific UX issue or concern.

Comment: Hi manju. This question is not relevant to this StackExchange site. You can learn more about the types of issues we handle here by taking the [Tour](http://ux.stackexchange.com/tour). There may be a different [StackExchange](http://www.stackexchange.com) site that can help you better with this type of question.

Comment: this belongs on either Ubuntu.SE or SuperUser.SE.